# Trouble getting file revisions from dropbox paper - python SDK

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I am using the python SDK for Dropbox to make updates to 'Dropbox Paper' documents. In order to achieve this I need to be able to get the latest file revision number.

This can be done using [`files_list_revisions`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_revisions) but I cannot get it to work. I've spent hours troubleshooting and I'm at a total loss. I'm trying to get the revisions using the doc id instead of the file path which appears to be possible according to documentation. To my knowledge Dropbox Paper files do not have file paths so using the doc id is the only way to go.

currently my code looks like this...

```
import dropbox
from dropbox.files import ListRevisionsMode

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')

dbx.files_list_revisions('my_doc_id', mode=ListRevisionsMode('my_doc_id'))
```

this returns `AssertionError: Invalid tag`

I have also tried

`dbx.files_list_revisions('my_doc_id', mode=ListRevisionsMode.id)`

which returns

```
dropbox.stone_validators.ValidationError: 'my_doc_id' did not match pattern '/(.|[\r\n])*|id:.*|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

The goal is to get the latest revision number and then update the Paper doc using

`dbx.paper_docs_update(data_to_append, 'append', revision_num, 'plain_text')`

Update:

I read the regex pattern from the second error and it appears the file id should be written like this `id:my_doc_id`

I made this correction and got a new error.

```
dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ApiError('my_doc_id', ListRevisionsError('path', LookupError('not_found', None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `files_list_revisions` method (as well as the other `files` methods), are only for interacting with Dropbox files/folders, not Paper documents.

There isn't a way to programmatically retrieve Paper document revisions, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.

Comment: This seems interesting to me becuase there is a `paper_docs_update` method that requires the revision number in order to update. Without the revision number the update method is useless.

Comment: Yes, [the `revision` parameter on /2/paper/docs/update](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#paper-docs-update) is there "to prevent colliding writes." It needs to match the previous value so you don't accidentally overwrite new changes. The API doesn't offer a way to list all of the revisions though.